# Jquery- calling functions after a fixed interval onload body having a condition

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to call an ajax function in JavaScript. `showusers(num)` having the condition that it should load up when the `body` loads and continue loading every 4-5 seconds.

```
<a href="#" id="user1" class="users">sdasd</a>
<a href="#" id="user2" class="users">asds</a>
```

The condition lies that the num variable should be the value at the end of `id` `user1`, `user2` ie *1* and *2* respectively. These `id`s should belong to the class `users`.

I tried adding an `onload` function to the a tag directly, but it doesn't seem to work since I am refreshing the content and echoing it at times using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

In [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ajax here. This will fire when the page loads.
});
```

and try looking at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) for timed javascript functions.

jQuery has an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function too.

Comment: Ya that is obvious what I want is the code to connect the firing of the function showusers(num) and the fetching of the value from the ids together

Comment: Why not have the function showusers(num) fetch the values of the id's then do its function? Do you by chance have a demonstration somewhere?